# Invalid Use of Null Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, null, vba, runtime-error

I'm attempting to write the code for a login system for an Access database I'm working on, and everything is running smoothly apart from this one error. 
I'm getting an

> Invalid Use of Null

error after I put the login details into the login form I've created, which works fine. The problem is with the code that is supposed to restrict the forms viewable to "Read-Only" if a user only has read permissions. I've done a bit of looking into the issue, and it would seem that the error is caused by VBA attempting to read an integer from a field with a NULL value, but VBA won't tell me exactly where the error is, only the line.

I'm posting the code I have for the actual Navigation form in the hopes that someone can point out where my error is so I can set about fixing it. This is the only issue my login system has, it's just a case of identifying where the problem actually is so I can implement any changes needed, as I have a feeling it's having problems identifying where the actual Userlevel value is coming from.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim UserLogin As String

Dim UserLevel As Integer

UserLogin = Environ("UserName")
Me.TxtLogin = UserLogin
UserLevel = DLookup("[UserType]", "TblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.TxtLogin 
& "'")
If UserLevel = 3 Then
    Me.AllowAdditions = False
    Me.AllowDeletions = False
    Me.AllowEdits = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try writing `UserLevel = 3` in stead of this ->`UserLevel = DLookup("[UserType]", "TblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.TxtLogin 
& "'")` and see whether you still get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not mention where the error happened.  I suppose it is on line

```
UserLevel = DLookup("[UserType]", "TblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.TxtLogin & "'")
```

You should `Dim UserLevel as Variant` since `Dlookup` may return a `Null`.

Alternatively, you can leave `UserLevel as Integer` and use:

```
UserLevel = Nz(DLookup("[UserType]", "TblUser", "[UserLogin] = " & Me.TxtLogin & "'"),0)
```

to turn a possible `Null` into a 0.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The first option worked, however now the code for the Priviledges doesn't seem to work. I'm probably missing something and need to put it in for the subforms though, i'll look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `NZ()` function to escape nulls.

```
Nz(Value, ValueIfNull )
```

---

```
UserLevel = DLookup("[UserType]", "TblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & NZ(Me.TxtLogin,"") & "'")
```

Reference:[Application.Nz Method (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-nz-method-access)

@PatrickHonorez brings up a good point.  But you can also use the `NZ` function to wrap the `DLookup`.

```
UserLevel = NZ(DLookup("[UserType]", "TblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & NZ(Me.TxtLogin,"") & "'"),"")
```

Comment: @Vityata the `DLookup` has the `UserLogin` field value wrapped in single quotes.  If `UserLogin` is a numeric field it will throw an error because of the single quotes.  In the case of a numeric field use `NZ(Me.TxtLoginID, 0)`.